# Aligning text above line using label.new

Tags: pine-script

I'm trying to align the text I have above a line so that the first letter in the label aligns perfectly with the left edge of the line regardless of the timeframe we are viewing. [Here is a link to the image showing how it currently appears](https://www.dropbox.com/s/rvmmorcz0qzzn0j/ADR%20Example.png?dl=0).

Here's the code:

```
draw_adr_hilo(hi_level, lo_level, res, adr, level_color) =>
var line hi_line = na
var line lo_line = na
if new_bar(res)
    line.set_x2(hi_line, bar_index)
    line.set_x2(lo_line, bar_index)
    line.set_extend(hi_line, extend.none)
    line.set_extend(lo_line, extend.none)
    hi_line := line.new(bar_index, hi_level, bar_index, hi_level, extend=extend.right, color=level_color)
    lo_line := line.new(bar_index, lo_level, bar_index, lo_level, extend=extend.right, color=level_color)
    label.new(bar_index, hi_level, "Average Range: " + tostring(to_pips(adr),'#.##') + " pips", xloc.bar_index, yloc.price, style=label.style_none, textcolor=color.white)
if not na(hi_line) and line.get_x2(hi_line) != bar_index
    line.set_x2(hi_line, bar_index)
    line.set_x2(lo_line, bar_index)
```

I tried manually changing the "bar_index" from 0 to another number however the text in the label kept moving further to the left, away from the line.

I also have an additional question. I will like to have two lines of text above the line. For example, I currently have one label called the "Average Range", can you provide guidance needed to add another label either above or below the current one? So it will be "Average Range" and the price of the hi_line above or below.

Thanks so much, I appreciate you help!

Comment: You can concatenate strings to get multi-line text. For example, "Average Range\n" + tostring(hi_line)

Comment: @LostinKnowledge thank you for this! This in combination with LucF's answer solved the problem for me perfectly. I got exactly what I was looking for. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

Precise horizontal alignment will be problematic because text is centered in the label. Looks good here but will not be perfect at all chart TFs. See `lbl3` in this code.

For extra lines above, answer above will work. For lines both above and below the line, see `lbl1` and `lbl2` in code:

```
//@version=4
study("Labels on Lines", "", true)
yp = highest(20)
newYp = change(yp)
if newYp
    // Labels up and down are used to print above and below line, with invisible color so we don't see them.
    lbl1 = label.new(bar_index, yp, "Above1\nAbove2", color=#00000000, style=label.style_labeldown, textcolor=color.green)
    lbl2 = label.new(bar_index, yp, "Below1\nBelow2", color=#00000000, style=label.style_labelup, textcolor=color.red)
    // Label none is used here because aligns vertically above line.
    // Left padding of text with spaces must vary with length of string since text is centered.
    // Horizontal alignment won't always be perfect.
    lbl3 = label.new(bar_index, yp, "            On Line", style=label.style_none, size=size.large, textcolor=color.orange, xloc=xloc.bar_index)
    if newYp[1]
        // Delete previous label when there is a consecutive new high, as there's no line plot in that case.
        label.delete(lbl1[1])
        label.delete(lbl2[1])
        label.delete(lbl3[1])
plot(newYp ? na : yp, "", color.gray, 2, plot.style_linebr, offset = -1)
```

[image]

Comment: Gosh, Luc, amazing! :)

Comment: Thanks @LucF, this solved the problem for me. Funny thing is I tried using spaces before but it didn't appear to make any difference. I just didn't use enough.

Comment: One option is to use [Unicode white spaces](http://jkorpela.fi/chars/spaces.html). This character ( ), for example, is U+2003, an em space that will require fewer spaces to produce the same effect. Using combos of en and em spaces, you can achieve finer control of positioning, but it will nonetheless vary with different chart resolutions.